# jQuery val() returning previously selected element value

Tags: php, jquery

I have a javascript function that handle dynamic IDs from a table.

TABLE:

```
<table border = "0" width = "95%"  class = "table table-striped table-bordered" id = "tblInfoChecks">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><center>#</center></th>
            <th><center>Category</center></th>
            <th><center>Name</center></th>
            <th><center>Date</center></th>
            <th><center>Due Date</center></th>
            <th><center>Allocation</center></th>
            <th><center>Status</center></th>
            <th><center>TAT</center></th>
            <th><center>Action</center></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php                   
            $q = "SELECT * FROM checks WHERE candidate_id = '$case_id' AND client_id = '$client_id'";
            $res = mysql_query($q);
            $numR = mysql_numrows($res);
            $y = 0;

            while($y < $numR){

                $m = $y + 1;
                $check_id = mysql_result($res, $y, "case_id");          
                $check_name = mysql_result($res, $y, "check_name"); //hidden
                $check_cat = mysql_result($res, $y, "check_category"); //hidden
                $elements = mysql_result($res, $y, "elements"); //hidden

                //verified information -- hidden
                $ver_status = mysql_result($res, $y, "ver_status");
                $ver_remarks = mysql_result($res, $y, "ver_remarks");
                $ver_action = mysql_result($res, $y, "ver_action");
                $overall_status = mysql_result($res, $y, "overall_status");

                $check_date = mysql_result($res, $y, "date_to_process");
                $check_due_date = mysql_result($res, $y, "due_date");
                $ver_id = mysql_result($res, $y, "verifier_id");
                $check_status = mysql_result($res, $y, "status");


                //hidden elements
                echo '<input type = "text" style = "" id = "txtInfoCheckID'.$y.'" value = "'.$check_id.'" />';
                echo '<input type = "text" style = "" id = "txtInfoCheckName'.$y.'" value = "'.$check_name.'" />';
                echo '<input type = "text" style = "" id = "txtInfoCheckCat'.$y.'" value = "'.$check_cat.'" />'; 
                echo '<input type = "text" style = "" id = "txtInfoCheckElements'.$y.'" value = "'.$elements.'" />';
                echo '<input type = "text" style = "" id = "txtInfoCheckVerStatus'.$y.'" value = "'.$ver_status.'" />';
                echo '<input type = "text" style = "" id = "txtInfoCheckVerRemarks'.$y.'" value = "'.$ver_remarks.'" />';
                echo '<input type = "text" style = "" id = "txtInfoCheckVerAction'.$y.'" value = "'.$ver_action.'" />';
                echo '<input type = "text" style = "" id = "txtInfoCheckOverallStatus'.$y.'" value = "'.$overall_status.'" />';

                //get verifier name
                $ver = "SELECT name FROM employees WHERE id = '$ver_id'";
                $ver_res = mysql_query($ver);
                $ver_numR = mysql_numrows($ver_res);
                if($ver_numR != 0){
                    $ver_name = mysql_result($ver_res, 0 ,0);
                } 

                //compute TAT
                $check_date_sec = strtotime($check_date);
                $today = strtotime(date("m/d/Y", time()));
                $tat = $today - $check_date_sec;
                $time_arr = secondsToTime($tat);
                $final_tat = $time_arr["d"]; //tat

                echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td><center>'.$m.'</center></td>
                        <td><center>'.$check_cat.'</center></td>
                        <td><center>'.$check_name.'</center></td>
                        <td><center>'.$check_date.'</center></td>
                        <td><center>'.$check_due_date.'</center></td>
                        <td><center>'.$ver_name.'</center></td>
                        <td><center>'.$check_status.'</center></td>
                        <td><center>'.$final_tat.'</center></td>
                        <td><center><a href = "javascript: void(0);" id = "viewInfoCheckElements'.$y.'">View Elements</a></center></td>
                    </tr>                   
                ';              

                $y++;
            }

        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th><center>#</center></th> 
            <th><center>Category</center></th>
            <th><center>Name</center></th>
            <th><center>Date</center></th>
            <th><center>Due Date</center></th>
            <th><center>Allocation</center></th>
            <th><center>Status</center></th>
            <th><center>TAT</center></th>
            <th><center>Action</center></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

JS

```
var rowCount_infoChecks = $('#tblInfoChecks >tbody >tr').length;                                                                                    
for(var i = 0; i < rowCount_infoChecks; i++)
{ViewInfoChecks(i);}
```

ViewInfoChecks:

```
function ViewInfoChecks(place){
        $('#viewInfoCheckElements'+place).livequery(function(){
            $('#viewInfoCheckElements'+place).live("click", function(e){
                var check_id = $('#txtInfoCheckID'+place).val();
            alert(check_id);                
                var check_name = $('#txtInfoCheckName'+place).val();                
                var check_cat = $('#txtInfoCheckCat'+place).val();
                var check_elem = $('#txtInfoCheckElements'+place).val();
                var ver_status = $('#txtInfoCheckVerStatus'+place).val();
                var ver_remarks = $('#txtInfoCheckVerRemarks'+place).val();
                var ver_action = $('#txtInfoCheckVerAction'+place).val();
                var overall_status = $('#txtInfoCheckOverallStatus'+place).val();


                $.post(
                    "posts/view-check-elements.php",
                    {
                        check_name : check_name,
                        check_cat : check_cat,
                        check_elem : check_elem,
                        ver_status : ver_status,
                        ver_remarks : ver_remarks,
                        ver_action : ver_action,
                        overall_status : overall_status
                    },
                    function(data){
                        $('#popupViewInfoChecks').html(data);
                        $('#popupViewInfoChecks').lightbox_me({
                            centered: true
                        });
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                );

            });
        });
    }
```

Every time I load the table to a div element using `$('#').html(data);` it loaded properly and I try to unhide the hidden values and the element values are properly placed. But when I access it through a `$('#').val()` and alert the values it becomes inconsistent. Sometimes when I access the element the previous selected value is the one that is appearing so my assumption is it is related to the browser but when I try to clear the cache it still appearing so I think the problem is my code.

Example:

- The value of the input selector with ID myID0 is "boy";
- I alert the value of myID0 and the value boy is correct
- I try to load the table again and query different values so the boy
  becomes girl
- I alert the value of the same selector myID0, the value is still boy
  and the newly assigned value(girl) was not recognized by the selector
  myID0.val();

Comment: Post the rendered html, and/or post it on jsFiddle. The php code here won't help much. What jquery version are you using?

Comment: I can't recreate the error on JSFiddle, basically it will just get the value of the element correctly. The thing is, I load the table on different divs and the table consist of only one ID which is the "tblInfoChecks". Do you think it is better to create different ID for the tables on different instances?? I am using jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: @JohnMicahFernandezMiguel, diffrent divs are in same page? Then you check the ID of each element. You cant have more than one element with same ID in a single page

Comment: basically the divs are popups. I have 4 tabs, All checks, Escalated Checks, Stopped Checks, and Fulfilled checks. each tabs has tables with the same ID and have different popups with the same IDs also.

Comment: so when I navigate through the tabs and click the "View More Info" on the table the values I get becames inconsistent

Comment: Do you get values from the other tables in the other tabs?

Comment: Do these popups are embedded in same page or do you have separate page for each popup like window.open("table1.php"),window.open("table2.php")

Comment: yes I get the values but when I repeatedly get values from different tabs sometimes I get the value from the table from the previous tabs instead of the current table from the current tab

Comment: Hard to nail down bro. Maybe post a live example?

Comment: Okay wait, I'll try to recreate it

Comment: It's pretty hard to recreate. anyway, how do you guys handle dynamic elements in javascript. for example I have elemens with ID on a loop (id0, id1, id2, ..... ) how do I access the values of each elements in javascript/jquery?

Comment: The way you are doing it inside the loop seems legit. But it seems that when you reload the table it still has the old values. When you say that you load the table again, do you mean you refresh the page, or what?

Comment: please paste in the part of the code wherein you are alerting the value

Answer (score 0):

Might be some sort of issue due to the selector / time to load the html. I'd try something like this:

```
function(data){
    var $popupViewInfoCheck = $('#popupViewInfoChecks');
    $popupViewInfoCheck.html(data);
    $popupViewInfoCheck.lightbox_me({
        centered: true
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

..and by the way, you should always be assigning your selectors to a variable when possible for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function ViewInfoChecks(place){
        $('#viewInfoCheckElements'+place).livequery('click',function(){
                var check_id = $('#txtInfoCheckID'+place).val();
            alert(check_id);                
                var check_name = $('#txtInfoCheckName'+place).val();                
                var check_cat = $('#txtInfoCheckCat'+place).val();
                var check_elem = $('#txtInfoCheckElements'+place).val();
                var ver_status = $('#txtInfoCheckVerStatus'+place).val();
                var ver_remarks = $('#txtInfoCheckVerRemarks'+place).val();
                var ver_action = $('#txtInfoCheckVerAction'+place).val();
                var overall_status = $('#txtInfoCheckOverallStatus'+place).val();


                $.post(
                    "posts/view-check-elements.php",
                    {
                        check_name : check_name,
                        check_cat : check_cat,
                        check_elem : check_elem,
                        ver_status : ver_status,
                        ver_remarks : ver_remarks,
                        ver_action : ver_action,
                        overall_status : overall_status
                    },
                    function(data){
                        $('#popupViewInfoChecks').html(data);
                        $('#popupViewInfoChecks').lightbox_me({
                            centered: true
                        });
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                );

            });

    }
```